# Why does JavaFX only receive mouse events once?

Tags: javafx, event-handling, mouseevent, fxml

I'm working on an application  where I can drag and drop an ImageView anywhere on to the scene. When I run the application it works fine the first time I drag the ImageView, but is unresponsive after I release it.

Here is my FXML Controller:

```
@FXML
private ImageView card;

@FXML
private void handleCardMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Drag Entered");
    DropShadow dropShadow=new DropShadow();
    dropShadow.setColor(Color.rgb(18,139,237));
    dropShadow.setSpread(.48);
    card.setEffect(dropShadow);
    card.setMouseTransparent(true);
    event.consume();
}

@FXML
private void handleCardMouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
    System.out.println("In Drag");
    card.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX());
    card.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY());
    event.consume();
}
@FXML
private void handleCardMouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    System.out.println("Exit Drag");
    card.setEffect(null);
    event.consume();
}
```

[Video of What is Happening](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=33ogkky%3E&s=8#.VRBaMPnF-ap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `mouseTransparent` to `true` in the `handleMouseCardPressed` method.

If you need to do this for some other reason (I can't see why you would), then in `handleCardMouseReleased(...)` you need to set `mouseTransparent` back to false:

```
    card.setMouseTransparent(false);
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragImageViewExample extends Application {

    private ImageView card;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, Color.CORAL);
        card = new ImageView(rect.snapshot(null, null));

        card.setOnMousePressed(this::handleCardMousePressed);
        card.setOnMouseDragged(this::handleCardMouseDragged);
        card.setOnMouseReleased(this::handleCardMouseReleased);

        Pane pane = new Pane(card);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void handleCardMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Drag Entered");
        DropShadow dropShadow=new DropShadow();
        dropShadow.setColor(Color.rgb(18,139,237));
        dropShadow.setSpread(.48);
        card.setEffect(dropShadow);
        event.consume();
    }

    private void handleCardMouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println("In Drag");
        card.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX());
        card.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY());
        event.consume();
    }

    private void handleCardMouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
        System.out.println("Exit Drag");
        card.setEffect(null);
        event.consume();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```